# When to move to the next Node.js release

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I have a working Node.js app using v6.10.
I saw that current recommended version at [Nodejs.org](https://nodejs.org/en/) is 8.9.

If I don't have any special need for the v8.9 features, is there a good reason to move forward?
In addition, I'm running on AWS Lambda, so moving to the newer version means I'll need to upload a runtime with my code, which seems as a clear con.

Comment: I just note that v6.10 lacks a major security patch. https://nodejs.org/en/blog/vulnerability/oct-2017-dos/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely wait until 8.x is supported by AWS Lambda natively instead of packaging the runtime in your Lambda deployment package.

There are certainly many advantages in 8.x over 6.x, such as async/await. If you don't currently need any of the newer features then you certainly don't need to rush to upgrade. However at some point after Amazon adds 8.x support to Lambda they will deprecate 6.x support and send you a message that you need to upgrade.

Comment: The advantage to bundling all your dependencies is that you are less prone to having the rug pulled from under you.  But for simplicity and effectiveness, I agree with @MarkB .

Comment: Bundling dependencies yes, but bundling the entire language interpreter? If you do that you still have to have some other target language for your Lambda function that does nothing but execute a command like `node8 lambda.js`. In that scenario the target environment can still get "pulled out from under you".

Comment: You're right, of course.  Thanks for the correction!  - but then, it *could* be turtles all the way down.